# How to optimize a scrolling UITableView while getting the exact location of UITableViewCell's?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, performance-testing

Imagine a plain UITableView with a list of 200 rows.
Some of those rows are custom, masquerading as UI `Section` header rows, and having support for being *sticky* when they reach the top.

Much like the stock iOS *Contacts* app.

As the user scrolls the tableview, it tracks the location of those custom section rows in the scrollview and manages when they should stick, and when they should release to scroll off the top for other section rows to replace it.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    ...
    for sectionRow in allSectionRows {

        let sectionRowRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: sectionRow.indexPath)
        let rowPositionY = sectionRowRect.origin.y + -tableView.contentOffset.y

        // ... compare rowPositionY if it has reached or passed
        // its sticky location in tableview
    }
    ...
}
```

While this works well to track the location of each row, I discovered that scaling it with ~50 section rows creates a performance hit.  Causing slower iOS devices to scroll at ~10-15fps, which breaks the smooth user experience.

It has shown in my testing that `tableView.rectForRow()` and `tableView.contentOffset.y` are the culprits in processing time.  Removing either one immediately improves smoother scrolling.  Of course it then breaks the functionality.

I tried caching `sectionRowRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: sectionRow.indexPath)`, but then get an odd artifact where the `rowPositionY` seems to drift.

What kind of possible optimizations could be considered to resolve this loop?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use the built in table sections headers instead?

Comment: Because I in fact have nested section headers in reality, but wanted to simplify the example here.  The built-in tableview only supports one level of section headers.

Comment: will nested sections expand or collapse? Maybe the nested ones can be a `UITableViewCell` with `UITableView` inside that has these nested sections. You can calculate the height of that cell that contains the table and so that nested table doesn't have to scroll.

Comment: so You still use the native built in sections and u don't have to reinvent the wheel.